# What's the best clustering algorithm for Fraud Data?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, clustering, unsupervised-learning, concept-drift

## Background

I'm working on a Fraud dataset with 500,000 samples, and 130 features.

There are:

- 98 numerical features,
- 32 categorical features,

There are missing values in:

- 7 numerical features,
- 12 categorical features,

20 of the categorical features have cardinalities above 10.

The fraud incidence is 1.5%.

I have built a Gradient Boosted Tree model on this dataset that has a GINI of 0.94 on a validation sample. I believe this means there are useful patterns in my data distributions.

I want to cluster the data in the dataset so that I can make small perturbations to each cluster and measure how the model performs. I want to do this to analyse the potential affect of data drift on the model.

I have limited compute: 10GB of RAM, a 4 core CPU, and no GPU acceleration.

## Question

What's the best clustering algorithm for this use case?

Comment: I would precede this with the question: What's the best distance (or similarity) measure to use in this case?
Do you already have a distance measure in mind? Do you understand your features, do you want to learn or impose weights for them? This question is (or should be) quite independent of the question of which clustering method to use but equally important. I do not have suggestions - I'm just curious.

Comment: I haven't decided that. Do you think I should ammend this question or ask another one?

Comment: My question is really just curiosity. It's an important aspect and possible to make good and bad choices. I have not had to make these choices myself. I  assume there might be quite a few stack sites already with q/a for this - your question is fine as it is I think. I mainly have experience with network clustering; your data could be a natural fit for a sparse network representation (e.g. compute similarities, perhaps inspect a histogram, decide a cutoff), followed by network clustering.

Answer (score 1):

I woud propose to start simple. For now, you are just "exploring" your data and it is okay to *cut corners*.

- To make your life easier, convert your categorical variables to numerical. For example, via [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). This is not perfect, but one step to simplify your analyses in your "exploratory" phase. Having numerical features allows you to apply many more methodologies with ease. The `missing` values can become a specific `column`/`feature` if you think their presense could be meaningful.
- Understand how your data looks like: For this, I often use [tSNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html). Try to change the `perplexity` parameter and see which one provides you with the best clustering. If you already have some intuition about number of clusters that you would expect, use this prior knowledge to find your "optimal" `perplexity` parameter.
- Once you have that, try to see which feature(s) are defining your clustering, by for example [forward/backward selection](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/12/introduction-to-feature-selection-methods-with-an-example-or-how-to-select-the-right-variables/).

With the above understandings, I would then go ahead with the perturbation analyses that you have in mind.

For your outlier detection, you may want to try `one-class` [classifiers](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-class-classification-algorithms). There are specifically designed to find your outliers.

Notes:

- The links are just my first Google search hit. They might not necessarily be the best reference.
- See @micans comment regarding tSNE application, which most of them I agree with. TLDR: tSNE representation is valid when two points (that are represented on the tSNE map) are close to each other. We can not say much about two far away points. Side note: It is impossible to fully represent the high-dimensional space in a lower dimensions. tSNE uses the above trick to make this possible (i.e., no *free lunch*!).

Comment: Interesting! Thank you, I'd never heard of tSNE before.

Comment: I would urge caution with inferring from a tSNE plot. Compressing high-dimensional data into two dimensions inevitably leads to the possibility of incomplete and/or misleading representation. With that caveat in mind these plots can be useful to gain insights into the data, but they cannot be said with any certainty to accurately represent or summarise the data, and as far as I'm aware there is no way of knowing the discrepancy. These plots are used a lot in single-cell genomic; see e.g. [this critique](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.08.25.457696v1) for caveats.